# How can i split character with string which has multiple characters

Tags: swift

Shortly I want to convert following string

"111---222-333"

to

"111",   "222-333".

So I want to split with only "---" string, not with "-".

Java split can do it, but if i use str1.split(separator: "---") with "---",

then it says "Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Character'"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than `split`, there is also a method called [`components(separatedBy:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/stringprotocol/2923413-components) that accepts a `StringProtocol` as the parameter:

```
"111---222-333".components(separatedBy: "---")
```